# Is there a good way to balance UDP packets over multiple ports?

Tags: networking, udp, wireguard

I'm not really sure where to turn, so I'm hoping that someone can help me out.

My ISP is very aggressive with various types of throttling.

It throttles UDP traffic by port. With incoming UDP traffic on multiple ports, I can max out my connection, but with UDP traffic on a single port, there is a very annoying throttle.

My goal is to have a Wireguard VPN or any other kind of UDP tunnel which can balance packets over multiple ports in order to overcome this throttling, with the end goal of being able to open a single tcp connection over this tunnel and achieve full bandwidth.

I have a VPS which is capable of maxing out my connection to experiment with. I have tried setting iptables rules to load balance outgoing UDP packets on the server end, and forward them all to the single port on my end, but my UDP knowledge is not good enough to really understand why it actually come over the multiple ports. My understanding is something like session stickiness causing it to continue to use the same port.

I have also tried things like mptunnel, mlvpn, glorytun, and other things I have found, but the results have not been good. The best result I have is using kcptun, which lets me specify multiple listening and connecting ports, but it only load balances them per session, so one single-threaded download over TCP would not be going over multiple UDP ports, while a multi-threaded download can max out my connection.

It feels like there should be a simple iptables rule or a load balancing udp proxy I can use to achieve this, but my know-how is basically at an end.

If anybody has ideas to achieve this, I would be very grateful to test them.  Currently MPTCP is my best solution, but some kind of UDP solution would be faster and greatly preferred.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to establish the connection between your home and the VPS? In other words, do you control both sides? One approach would be to randomly assign UDP destination ports using some evenly distribute characteristic of the outgoing packet (e.g. some bits of the checksum header field) to a fixed range at the VPS  and then rewrite the whole range to a single port in your home. That should work with some iptable rules. Then you can use any tunnel via UDP.

Comment: I am very grateful for your response. Yes. I want to establish it between my home and the VPS, and I do control both sides. What you propose seems like it very well could work, but I'm not sure what the iptables rules might look like. Would it be too much trouble to give an example?